# Trim and Clean Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can Trim my dada with the script below

But is there a way Clean data in Google using a Google Script similar to Clean in VBA?

i.e. Remove all non-printing characters

I am unable to find-replace on data copied and pasted into GS from another source

Thanks

```
function trimSpacesSHT(shtName) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(shtName);
 var activeRange = sheet.getDataRange();

  // Read Height and Width only once
  var maxHeight = activeRange.getHeight();
  var maxWidth = activeRange.getWidth();

  // Read all values and formulas at once
  var rangeValues = activeRange.getValues();
 // iterate through all cells in the selected range
 for (var cellRow = 0; cellRow < maxHeight; cellRow++) {
    for (var cellColumn = 0; cellColumn < maxWidth; cellColumn++) {
    rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn] = rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn].toString().trim().replace(/\s(?=\s)/g,'');
  }
}
 // Write back all values at once
 activeRange.setValues(rangeValues);
}
```

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do

Comment: Remove all nonprinting characters

Comment: What do you mean by `I am unable to find-replace on data copied and pasted into GS from another source`? What is your goal? Where are you pasting text? What have you tried to do with existing `String` methods?

Comment: =arrayformula(clean(a1:d500)) will work too

Comment: Just a warning, this trim function can corrupt some of your data. Example: A cell value of 8055-1 turns into January 1st 8055 (probably due to the toString() method). It works in most cases though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CLEAN method of VBA removes the characters of `0-31, 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157`. You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script? If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Because I was interested in this method and want to study about this, I created this.

### Sample script :

```
function cleanForGAS(str) {
  if (typeof str == "string") {
    var escaped = escape(str.trim());
    for (var i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
      var s = i.toString(16);
      var re = new RegExp("%" + (s.length == 1 ? "0" + s : s).toUpperCase(), "g");
      escaped = escaped.replace(re, "");
    }
    var remove = ["%7F", "%81", "%8D", "%8F", "%90", "%9D"];
    remove.forEach(function(e) {
      var re = new RegExp(e, "g");
      escaped = escaped.replace(re, "");    
    });
    return unescape(escaped).trim();
  } else {
    return str;
  }
}
```

### Usage :

When you use this, please modify your script.

#### From :

```
rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn] = rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn].toString().trim().replace(/\s(?=\s)/g,'');
```

#### To :

```
rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn] = cleanForGAS(rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn].toString());
```

### Reference :

- [WorksheetFunction.Clean Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-clean-method-excel)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you, you understood very well

Comment: @xyz Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. And I could also study from your question. Thank you, too.